# How to get the file path to put into the Documents.open so I can work with this 2nd document in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Windows 10 and Office 2016.

I am trying to use microsoft word VBA to open and use a second document.

```
Set wdDialogFilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
selectedpath = wdDialogFilePicker.Select 'selectedpath is type string
Set sCheckDoc = GetObject(selectedpath) 'open Word 
Set docRef = Documents.Open(sCheckDoc) 'docRef is type Variant
```

It gives me type errors.

Nor can I find the path name to the document on my computer - it says file not found.

```
Set docRef = Documents.Open(" \\Darwin\c$\Users\Darwin\Desktop\2ndDoc.doc")
```

Can you help me get the file path to put into the Documents.open so I can work with this 2nd document in Word?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Set wdDialogFilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
selectedpath = wdDialogFilePicker.Select 
Set docRef = Documents.Open(selectedpath)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will cover the basics when wanting to select and open a file. Obvisouly there is alot more one can do to restrict the selection etc.

Please note this is for Office 2010, and I cant see that the references have changed.

```
Sub FileOpenSub()

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim docRef As Document

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
         .Title = "Select Word File To Open"
         .AllowMultiSelect = False
         .InitialFileName = "Desktop"

        If .Show <> 0 Then
            DocFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No File Selected"
        End If
    End With

    Set docRef = Documents.Open(DocFileName)

End Sub
```

Comment: I like this approach, and I've now used it for something similar.. so thank you. The only thing I did differently is to move the last line up into the conditional so that it only executes if a file is selected.